# Confirmation of polar coordinate calculation

Tags: calculus, limits, polar-coordinates

$$\lim_{x,y \to 0,0} \frac{x^2y + xy^2}{ x^2+y^2}$$

Polar coordinates

$$x= r \cdot \cos \theta$$
$$y = r \cdot \sin \theta$$

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{(r \cos \theta)(r \sin \theta) + (r \cos \theta) (r \cos \theta)}{(r \cos \theta)^2 + (r \sin \theta)}^2 =0$$

Am I right?

Comment: What does $\lim_{y\to0,0}$ mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Edited

Comment: How do you conclude $0$ ?? (Fix the typo.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. You should have got$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{(r \cos \theta)^2(r \sin \theta) + (r \cos \theta) (r \sin \theta)^2}{(r \cos \theta)^2 + (r \sin \theta)^2}\tag1$$instead. And $(1)$ is equal to $0$ because$$\frac{(r \cos \theta)^2(r \sin \theta) + (r \cos \theta) (r \sin \theta)^2}{(r \cos \theta)^2 + (r \sin \theta)^2}=r\bigl((\cos\theta)^2(\sin\theta)+(\cos\theta)(\sin\theta)^2\bigr).$$

Comment: Does this "r" in the denominator interfere when applying the identity?

Comment: Because in the denominator it's rcosx² + rsenx²

Comment: Denominator is jusr $r^2$ (recall $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$) while you have $r^3$ on numerator, all simplifies to just $r$ on numerator.

Answer (score 2):

Polar is fine, but in this particular case, this below is way simpler:

$$|x^2y+xy^2|\le |y|x^2+|x|y^2\le \underbrace{\max(|x|,|y|)}_{\to 0}\ (x^2+y^2)$$

Comment: you can also use the workaround that f (x, y) l ⩽ l xy (x + y) / (2xy) l = lx + yl, because 2xy ⩽ x² + y² (it would only be a problem in the even quadrants), and then would you follow the Squeeze theorem?

Comment: it is more of a gambiarra, because it presupposes the existence of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Your algebra is wrong in several places, but the limit is $0$. For an easy solution, squeeze the function between $\pm2r$.